# Question about object initialization semantics

Tags: c++, standards

I've been wondering about the language in the C++03 specification surrounding object initialization, specifically section 8.5 paragraph 9 which states,

*"If no initializer is specified for an object, and the object is of (possibly cv-qualified) non-POD class type (or
array thereof), the object shall be default-initialized; if the object is of const-qualified type, the underlying
class type shall have a user-declared default constructor. Otherwise, if no initializer is specified for a nonstatic
object, the object and its subobjects, if any, have an indeterminate initial value; if the object or any
of its subobjects are of const-qualified type, the program is ill-formed."*

I want to pay particular attention to the clause, *"Otherwise, if no initializer is specified for a nonstatic
object, the object and its subobjects, if any, have an indeterminate initial value"*.  According to section 8.5 paragraph 5, the definition of a default-initialization falls into three cases:

1. if T is a non-POD class type (clause 9), the default constructor for T is called (and the initialization is
   ill-formed if T has no accessible default constructor)
2. if T is an array type, each element is default-initialized
3. otherwise, the object is zero-initialized.

So as I understand it, paragraph 9 is stating that if we have a non-POD class type that does not have an initializer, then it's default constructor would be called.  What I'm confused by is what happens in the case of POD-class types ... it seems from the clause I highlighted that there is no mention of a default constructor call being required for POD-class types.  Yet if I created a POD-class type like

```
struct POD_class
{
    int a;
    int b;
    POD_class() { cout << "Default constructor called" << endl; }
};

int main()
{
    POD_class test;
    return 0;
}
```

the default constructor of `POD_class` seems to be called when this code is compiled and run with `g++`. Therefore, even if `POD_class` did not have a specific initializer, it seems it was still default-initialized, per case #1 in the definition of default-initialization, because a default constructor for the type was called.

Based on the above scenario, here is my question:  For a POD-class, does *not* default initializing an object as paragraph 9 mentions for non-static POD-classes mean that its default constructor is not called, or that it's simply not zero-initialized?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your `POD_class` is in fact not a POD class.  A POD class cannot have a user-declared constructor.

Comment: According to section 9.1 paragraph 4, *"A POD-struct is an aggregate class that has no non-static data members of type non-POD-struct, non-POD-union (or array of such types) or reference, and has no user-defined copy assignment operator and no user-defined destructor"* ... it doesn't seem to mention anything about user-defined constructors ...

Comment: @Jason:  Right:  That starts off "a POD-struct is an aggregate."  What is an aggregate?  "An aggregate is an array or a class with **no user-declared constructors**, no private or protected non-static data members, no base classes, and no virtual functions." (C++03 §8.5.1/1)

Comment: @Jason: Aggregate classes cannot have default constructors (except for the compiler-generated one).

Comment: Ah, okay, I see now ... that's 8.5.1 paragraph 1.  This makes a lot more sense.  Thanks :-)